# Binding of guid from body not possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I tried to make a PUT controller method that binds a Guid from the body but no matter what JSON I send as body, the Guid is always null. A minimal example of my function method looks like this:

```
[HttpPut("Test/{guidThatWorks:guid}")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(Guid guidThatWorks, [FromBody] Guid testId)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

When I call this method in Swagger or Postman, *guidThatWorks* is set correctly but *testId* is always null.
The body I'm sending is the following:

```
"cef0cbf3-6458-4f13-a418-ee4d7e7505df"
```

I then tried to change the type of *testId* to string and it worked perfectly fine.

After that, I wanted to know how it behaves with objects. So, I created the following test object:

```
public class TestRequest
{
    public Guid? TestId { get; set; }
    public string TestString { get; set; }
}
```

And changed my method as follows:

```
[HttpPut("Test/{guidThatWorks:guid}")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(Guid guidThatWorks, [FromBody] TestRequest testRequest)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Now, the following happens:
If I send this JSON body:

```
{
    "testString": "string"
}
```

*testRequest* gets instantiated, the value of *TestString* has the value "string" and *TestId* is null.

So, I at least know that the binding works in principle. But if I send a body that tries to set the Guid:

```
{
    "testString": "string",
    "testId": "cef0cbf3-6458-4f13-a418-ee4d7e7505df"
}
```

*testRequest* can't be bound again and is null.

Am I doing something wrong? I assume it works with *guidThatWorks* because it uses a different binder. But I found some sources that say you should be able to bind a Guid to the body, too.

**Edit:** This problem somehow resolved itself when I came back the next day and when I wanted to debug it again and check the model state, as someone suggested, it just worked. Seems like some weird bug that got fixed by rebooting my system or reopening Visual Studio...

Comment: why don't you take it as string and generate a `Guid` from it ?

Comment: If you look at `ModelState` then it will tell what went wrong with Binding. So which parameters could not be bound, and a bit of why it failed. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation

Comment: @MohammadHamoud I could as a workaround but it's really not elegant and can lead to a lot of unnecessary conversion work.

Comment: @PeterB Thanks for the tip, totally forgot about that! Unfortunately (?) when I came back to the project again today and wanted to see what's in the model state, it just worked. I really have no idea why. I'm the only one working on the project and I didn't change anything at all since yesterday.
Strange as it might sound, a reboot seems to have fixed the problem. Just hoping it won't come back.

Comment: @Yuk ummmm, you know you can just `new Guid(guidStr)` right ?
there is no *lot* of work here

Answer (score 4):

Your guid is just not valid. Guid is 16 bytes, so in hex form it should contain 32 characters. When parsing from string, .NET expects it in a form of:

```
XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX < 32 characters in total
```

However your guid contains 31 hex characters:

```
cef0cbf3-6458-4f13-a418-ee4d7e7505d
                                   ^ one is missing
```

So no surprise that it fails to bind.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the Guid wrong. My bad but thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

This problem somehow resolved itself when I came back the next day and when I wanted to debug it again and check the model state, as someone suggested, it just worked. Seems like some weird bug that got fixed by rebooting my system or reopening Visual Studio.